# Programmatically bind content type to Excel file

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to create a content type (programmaticall) which can be bound to excel instead of word, and add it to a List Library so when you click create new document it opens a excel template. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [DocumentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.documenttemplate.aspx) property.

You can create content type programmatically in FeatureActivated event. Refer to the link below, it can help you get started:

http://jamesemann.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/creating-content-types-with-document-templates-in-code/

Comment: Thank you it was not exakt what I wanted but it helped me to solve my problem.